# jquery: get text between two <br> elements

Tags: jquery, html

i've got a HTML tree like this:

```
<pre id="code_block">
    This is line 1<br>
    This is line 2<br>
    This is line 3<br>
    This is line 4<span id="marker"></span><br>
    This is line 5<br>
    This is line 6<br>
    ...
</pre>
```

now, i need to get the text of the line where the marker span resists in...
i already have the two elements (leading < br> and < span>)

```
$('#marker');
$('#marker').prev('br');
```

but how to get the text between these?

I've already tried several solutions
but the problem is that the text between the two elements is not an own element...

ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate bit more !! what you want to see in end result?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve `This is line 4` then you can do like this:

```
var text = $('#marker').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue;
});

alert(text[0]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9PT/

Comment: Why are you using `map` method? When there is only one returned value.

Comment: Just for the sake of retrieving more than 1 time if necessary in the future.

Comment: Thanks to your reply I realized that in my case I need to use this.nextSibling and not $this.nextSibling !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `previousSibling` property:

```
document.getElementById('marker').previousSibling;
```

`previousSibling` returns an object, if you want to get the text content of it, you can use `textContent`, `nodeValue` or `wholeText` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/udsZe/

Answer (score 0):

nextUntil will help you..  check out the link

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/