# How can I style a part of text which is between two <br> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, jsfiddle

I'm trying to add CSS to a part of text from an XML rss feed (and I can't change it).
And what about using Javascript?

The problem is that I want it smaller with right-alignment.

The part of text I'm talking about is "This offer is valid till ##/##/##".

here is the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/WC5F8/1/

```
.itemContent br {
text-align:right;
font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: You need to place it within HTML tags to be able to apply style to that bit of text.

Comment: What would we do without JSFiddle!

Comment: my suggestion is add a span class to wrap your offer valid content in.

Comment: use **span** instead of **br** tag.

Comment: @Learning Read the first line of the question again.

Comment: Your markup is invalid

Comment: <br> is a self closing tag - nothing is contained in it. There is no <br><\br> in valid HTML (or that document).

Comment: You can select the containing div with document.getElementsByClassName('itemContent'). Or since you said jquery, $('div.itemContent')

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425087/jquery-get-text-between-two-br-elements

Comment: You should also mention that you loaded the RSS with FeedEk, that's an important detail ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript, you would need to modify the feed's html to wrap that piece of text in a div so that you can style it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WC5F8/2/

```
$(".itemContent").html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/(offerta valida fino al \d+\/\d+\/\d+)/i,"<div class='offervalid'>$1</div>");
});
```

css:

```
.itemContent .offervalid {
    float:right;
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Note, i think there's a typo in your sample code. Offer valid till 2031?

Comment: no typos, is just a test. ;-)
I see that this works great in jsfiddle but I'm trying to put this javascript into my html, and...it doesn't work (I had to change a couple of lines in Italian)

Comment: Most likely the regexp is wrong. I can't download that file due to my network, can you paste it in a pastebin instead? I'm only interested in the itemContent div.

Comment: html http://pastebin.com/6L0dNnw3
css http://pastebin.com/cnME7Uy0
FeedEk.js http://pastebin.com/smLMQvQT

Comment: I updated the code in the answer to match the text from the feed

Comment: this is what I have and it's not working :-S
http://jsfiddle.net/Etj8b/

it works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work on my html

Comment: the problem is not the regex, the problem is the asynchronous loading (see my answer, i added some explanations to it)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with just CSS, all the text in that `div` element is character data (CDATA) interspersed with the `br` elements. With CSS you can only target *entire* elements and their *entire* contents. If you cannot change or rewrite the HTML, you cannot restyle a subset of the CDATA of a single element.

With Javascript it's hard, since you have the same limitations of not being able to select entire elements. You'd have to start splitting content by arbitrary criteria, such as hoping there's always the same number of `<br>` elements. The solution would be inherently unstable.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible with just CSS, without Javascript, if you are willing to give up on hiding the `<br>`. That is to say, don't hide all the `<br>`s in the div, only the last one.

```
li > div > br:last-child {
    display:none;
}

.itemContent {font-size:.5em}
.itemContent::first-line {font-size:2em}
```

The trick is to halve the font size for the whole div, and then restore the first part of the div (up to the first br) to the original size.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WC5F8/9/)

Comment: +1 for creativity. I don't think it's a ***good*** solution but it'll work if all better solutions are really impossible.

Comment: this is great but showing the br will make apper some space under the img

Comment: @salamala That can be achieved by hiding the last br. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JavaScript is processed asynchronously. In [your code](http://tempsend.com/BB109AF206), jQuery will first look for any .itemContent elements (but will not find any). Then FeedEk loads the RSS file and inserts it's contents to the DOM. That's why your code doesn't work, you look for the elements too early.

You can only access the `.itemContent` elements after jQuery finished loading and processing the RSS. Unfortunately FeedEk doesn't provide a callback method, so you don't know when it finished. There is a workaround when you use jQuery's ajaxSetup. FeedEk internally uses jQuery's Ajax functions, which provide a way to invoke a function after the Ajax request and it's processing finished.

I tested this with the code you provided and it worked for me. Just replace your own FeedEk call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

  jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function () {
      $('.itemContent').each(function(i, element) {
        $($(element).find('br')[0].nextSibling)
        .wrap('<div class="offervalid"/>')
        .before('<br><br><br><br><br>'); // if you really need <br>s
      });
    }
  });

  $('#divRss').FeedEk({
    FeedUrl: 'http://dimmituquando.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default',
    MaxCount: 10
  });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is the solution!
But what if I want to give it a class instead of an inline style? (for future editings)

Comment: it's exactly the same, just replace the style="..." by a class="..."

Comment: great, but I had to mix it with code form Kevin B as I may want to add sever <br> before the "this offer is valid..."

Comment: It's not really good style to precede a <div> with <br>s. I would add a margin-top to the wrapping div (no matter if you use the wrapping version I posted or the KevinB's regex version)

Answer (score 0):

try this, using inline-style-tags:

```
<span style="text-align:right; font-size: 0.5em;">This offer is valid till ##/##/##</span>
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to add CSS to a part of text from an XML rss feed (**and I can't change it**)"*

Comment: he cant change the feed, but if he has javascript, and the feed, (both of which he does have) he can change the feed with javascript, resulting in the code from this answer.

Comment: @KevinB There are quite a few steps missing from between... Obviously this is what the OP wants, but the question is how to get there.

Comment: Right, but this answer puts exactly the same amount of effort toward solving it as the question does.

Comment: Additionally remember that `span` is an inline element and can't be right-alined unless you add something like `display: block`. In this case I would simply use a `div`.